# Highcharts / ASP.NET Highcharts DataLabel Dynamic Color Changes ( + Loop through labels)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, highcharts

Good Days.

I want to ask how to do a javascript custom array loop for the highcharts datalabels *(inside **plotOptions (?)**    ~correct me.)* 
*(labels/values are marked in blue color in the image below. named **IMAGE 1**)*
[(IMAGE 1) Please visit this link to see the chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HhUL.png)
* *i ask for your tolerance, since Stackoverflow doesn't allow me yet to embed images directly into the post* 

Meanwhile, the row of numbers *(+1.6, +1.3, +0.8, etc . .)* 
under the word 'Poin' above (*based on the image that i provide, the IMAGE 1*), I've managed the javascript for chart's custom injection.

here's the code,

```
chart.InitChart(new Chart
            {
                Type = ChartTypes.Bar,
                ClassName = "chart",
                MarginRight = 80,
                AlignTicks = false, 
                Events = new ChartEvents
                {
                    Load = @"function(){                
                                this.renderer.label('" + label1 + @"', this.plotWidth + this.plotLeft + 20 , 5, null, null, null, true).css({ color: '#000000' }).add();                                   
                                for (var i=0; i < this.series.length; i++) {                                             
                                    for (var p=0; p<this.series[i].points.length; p++){
                                        if (!this.series[i].points[p].isNull){                                              
                                            var point = this.series[i].points[p];
                                            var pxX = this.xAxis[0].toPixels(point.x, true);                                                                                                 
                                            var fcolor = '#000000';    
                                            var text ='';
                                             
                                            if( point.custom1 == undefined ){
                                                text = '-';
                                            }else if(point.custom1 == 0){
                                                text = point.custom1.toFixed(1);
                                            }
                                            else if( point.custom1 > 0 ){
                                                fcolor = 'green';
                                                text = '+' + point.custom1.toFixed(1);
                                            }
                                            else if (point.custom1 < 0 ){
                                                fcolor = 'red';
                                                text =  point.custom1.toFixed(1);
                                            }
                                            
                                            this.renderer.label(text, this.plotWidth + this.plotLeft + 20 , pxX + 20, null, null, null, true).css({ color: fcolor }).add();                                                                                                
                                        }
                                    }
                                }                                                                                                                                 
                            }",
                },
            })
```

and currently, 
i have a job where the objective here is to enhance the features on the Highcharts bar above in the following image.

[(IMAGE 2)Please visit this link to see the Mockup plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JAh4.png)
* and again, i ask for your tolerance, since Stackoverflow doesn't allow me yet to embed images directly into the post

as we can see in the User Interface/Mockup Planning above, the colors in the values/labels above change *(red and green)* following the comparison with the row of values next to them.

i meet some difficulties to make a loop function for each label/value and generate separate colors. i tried to make loop reference based on my first code snippet, but still failed. 
So far, here's my plotOptions code inside the ***function()***..

```
.SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Bar = new PlotOptionsBar
                {
                    Animation = new Animation(true),
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsBarDataLabels
                    {
                        Enabled = true,
                        Style = "color: 'black', textOutline: 'none', fontWeight: 'normal'",
                        Inside = true,
                        Align = HorizontalAligns.Center,
                        VerticalAlign = VerticalAligns.Middle,
                        Formatter = @"function(){ 
                                                  var text1 = this.y.toFixed(" + decimalDigit + @");
                                                  
                                                  if(this.series.name != 'L') 
                                                  {
                                                    text1 += '%';
                                                  }
                                                  return text1;
                                                }",
                        UseHTML = true
                    },
                    Events = new PlotOptionsBarEvents { Click = @"function (e) { sectionClickEvent(e.point.customName);}" }
                },
                Series = new PlotOptionsSeries
                {
                    GroupPadding = -0.1,
                }
            })
```

I welcome to receive answers in either **javascript** or **c#/.NET** format.
I'll try to fit the js-based hierarchies to .net format *(plotOptions, series, dataLabels, etc)* for your answers.

Thanks. Regards.

Comment: In short, you need to add a symbol (triangle) in the dataLabels and show it as needed to indicate either a decreasing or an increasing value, yes? You can use [dataLabels.filter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange.dataLabels.filter) to control with dataLabels are display. Other options is change dataLabels with [dataLabels.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange.dataLabels.formatter)

Comment: Yup, thanks @SebastianHajdus , i got my chart working as i wanted. thank you.